# Is it possible to make my footer fixed in the center and text keep on blinking with different colours

Tags: html, css, footer

This are my footer code. My aim is to have the footer in the center fixed and the text " welcome to tpopenhouse" keep on blinking with different colours

```css
}
.movement1 {
  /* footer movement*/
  
  height: 50px;
  background: #1976d2;
  position: relative;
  /*-webkit-animation: myfirst 1s 1; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  
  animation: myfirst1 6s 100000;
  /*Time of animation and 5s and 100000 cycle of animation on refreshing*/
  
  animation-direction: alternate;
  */
}
```

```html
<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="section  lighten-3 darken-2 white-text center " style="position:fixed;width: 80%;;bottom:0">
  <p class="flow-text movement1"> #TPOpenhouse & Stand To Win Prizes </p>
  <!-- Footer text -->
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### BUGS BE GONE

There is a bug that prevents css color animations from triggering in some browsers.

This can be worked around by including an alternate animation trigger at the start of the animation.

This can be anything other than color. In this case I have added `width:100%` as the trigger in the initial step.

You can see this bug in action by removing the `width:100%` from the initial step.

```css
footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px 10px;
  color: red;
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
    color: red;
  }
  25% {
    color: yellow;
  }
  50% {
    color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>#TPOpenhouse &amp; Stand To Win Prizes</footer>
```

### Centering in CSS

As for centering this can be simple. the traditional way is to simply use padding. The modern way is to use flex. The choice is yours.

**Flex example**

```css
footer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<footer>#TPOpenhouse &amp; Stand To Win Prizes<footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following to place your footer center fixed in the bottom:

Your footer is somewhat up from bottom of the page because you applied background color on `<p>` element which has the default margin so apply the background-color on `footer` instead of `<p>`.

```
footer {
    background: #1976d2;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

By applying `left` and `transform` property your footer will be placed in the center too.